# Adding specific record to binary file c++

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a binary file and text file of all record workers.
The default total month hours are all set to 0.
How to I actually access to the particular month in the binary and change it to the desired value?

This is in text file format

```
ID  Name   J F M
 1  Jane   0 0 0
 2  Mark   0 0 0
 3  Kelvin 0 0 0
```

to

```
ID  Name   J F M
 1  Jane   0 0 25
 2  Mark   0 0 30
 3  Kelvin 0 0 40
```

The 25 is actually the amount of hours worked in march.

Comment: Doing this with raw binary input/output is a real pain.  Do the records already exist, or are you going to be creating them?

Answer (score 3):

I think the first question here is what you mean by "binary". Are you showing the format of the file literally? In other words, at input, is the character going to be '0' or '\0'? When you're done, do you want the file to contain the two digits '3' and '0' or the single character '\25', '\30' or '\40'?

If you're dealing with a single character at a known offset in each record for input, and want to replace it by a single character for the result, things are pretty easy: seek to the right offset in the file, write a byte, seek to the next offset, and continue 'til you've updated all the records.

If the input file contains character strings, so when you update the value its length will (probably) change, then you're pretty much stuck with reading data in, modifying it in memory, and writing the new data back out (usually to a new file). This is pretty easy too, but can be slow if your file is large.

If you're doing this in a real program, I'd think twice about doing it on your own at all. I'd consider using something like [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) to handle the data instead. This not only allows you to simplify your code, but also makes life quite a bit nicer for your clients. It uses a [known/documented file format](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html), so other tools can work with the data, do backups, etc. It supports transactions, logging, roll-backs, etc. In short, they get a robust solution instead of yet another fragile problem.

Answer (score 1):

A file is a stream of bytes.  You can access a file by using the c family of functions fopen fread fwrite.  Or though c++ iostream operations.  In each case you will need to find the record usually by knowing its position and then reading and writing that record. If the records are not of fixed size you will have to handle moving all subsequent records.